# In Linux Terminal is it a dash sign can be use as a temporary filename?

Tags: linux, terminal, nmap

I'm new to Linux and I was learning nmap, I have a question about the dash sign, I saw a line of command in a tutorial which are

```
nmap -oG - 1.2.3.4 -p 22 -vv > /home/TEST
```

My question is after -oG a filename are required for the option, but why it can be skip if using dash sign as  the filename for the option? is it because of the dash sign is mean by temporary file or something else? Also it wont create a file named "-" in the /home/ directory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question and would be better served @ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means `stdout`, which would be `/home/TEST` in your example. You could also just use:

```
nmap -oG /home/TEST 1.2.3.4 -p 22 -vv
```

From [`man nmap`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap) (section *"Output"*):

> ... While these options save results to files, Nmap still prints interactive output to stdout as usual. For example, the command nmap -oX myscan.xml
>          target prints XML to myscan.xml and fills standard output with the same interactive results it would have printed if -oX wasn't specified at all.
>          **You can change this by passing a hyphen character as the argument to one of the format types. This causes Nmap to deactivate interactive output, and
>          instead print results in the format you specified to the standard output stream. So the command nmap -oX - target will send only XML output to
>          stdout..  Serious errors may still be printed to the normal error stream, stderr.** ...